# show and hide field from select (dropdown) in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter. In this, I have created drop down list using select,while selecting the first option, the fields that belongs to first option should be displayed. Similarly, while selecting 2nd option, the fields that belongs to second option should be displayed and the fields of first option should be hidden while entering inputs. I have tried script in view page and it's not working.

For Ex: I have 3 options such as bus,car and bikes. While selecting car, the fields should display automatically by just clicking car option. And the same way, while clicking the car option, the fields of the previous option should be hidden and display the current one.

view page:

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Vehicle_controller/addfun" method="post">
        <table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="8px" cellpadding="8px">
            <h1 style="margin-left:44%;">Vehicle owner details</h1>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle type:</td>
                <td><select class="veh" name="vehtype">
                    <option value="nil">Choose below:</option>
                    <option value="bus" id="bus">Bus</option>
                    <option value="car" id="car">Car</option>
                    <option value="bike" id="bike">Two wheeler</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="textbox" name="car" style="visibility:hidden;"/></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="bus">
                        <td>Bus type:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="type"></td>
                    </div></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="bus">
                            <td>Owner name:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="bus">
                            <td>License no:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="license"></td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="bus">
                            <td>Engine status:</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" id="success" name="eng" value="success">Success<br>
                            <input type="radio" id="failed" name="eng" value="failed">Failed</td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="bus">
                        <td>Purchased on:</td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="date"></td>
                    </div>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="bus">
                            <td>Vehicle status:</td>
                            <td><select name="status">
                                <option value="nil">choose below:</option>
                                <option value="using" id="using">Using</option>
                                <option value="sold" id="sold">Sold</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <div class="car">
                        <td>Car model:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="model"></td>
                    </div></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="car">
                            <td>Owner:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="carname"></td>
                        </div></tr>

                        <tr>
                            <div class="car">
                            <td>license no:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="carnum"></td>
                        </div></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="car">
                            <td>Car condition:</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="carradio" value="excellent">Excellent<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="carradio" value="bad">Bad</td>
                            </div></tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>

                    </tr>




            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#bus").click(function()
    {alert("bkbk");
        $(".bus").show(1000,"swing",function(){

        });
        $(".car").hide(1000,"swing",function(){

        });

    });

    $("#car").click(function()
    {
        $(".car").show(1000,"swing",function(){

        });
        $(".bus").hide(1000,"swing",function(){

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller page:

```
<?php
defined ("BASEPATH")OR exit('No direct script allowed');

class Vehicle_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('vehicle_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('vehicle_view');
    }

    public function addfun()
    {
        $vehtype=$this->input->post('vehtype');
        $type=$this->input->post('type');
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $license=$this->input->post('license');
        $eng=$this->input->post('eng');
        $date=$this->input->post('date');
        $status=$this->input->post('status');

        $data=array('vehtype'=>$vehtype,'type'=>$type,'name'=>'name','license'=>$license,'eng'=>$eng,'date'=>$date,'status'=>$status);
        $this->vehicle_model->datas($data);
        redirect('Vehicle_controller/index');
    }


}

?>
```

model page:

```
<?php
class vehicle_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function datas($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('vehicle',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code in view file like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.veh').on('change',function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "bus"){
            $( ".bus" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {});
            $( ".car" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {});

        }else if(value == "car"){
            $( ".bus" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {});
            $( ".car" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {});
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Or You can do it as well

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.veh').on('change',function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "bus"){
            $( ".bus" ).show();
            $( ".car" ).hide();

        }else if(value == "car"){
            $( ".bus" ).hide();
            $( ".car" ).show();
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I have edited my answer.You can try this one also @AdraRavindranC

Comment: sorry, still it doesn't work :( . actually why '.veh' should mention instead of id in 3rd statement of yours.

Comment: Becuse your select has `'.veh'` class. Using select box change event you can show/hide your element. Its a right way to do. So

Comment: is there any other option to give without onchange event. @Naim mMlek

Comment: No its a standard way

Comment: Can you check whether given onchange statement is right??

onchange="if (this.selectedIndex=='car'){this.myform['car'].style.visibility='visible'}else {this.myform['car'].style.visibility='hidden'};"